# QWizard: QWizardPage::registerField vs shared object pointer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Looking at the Qt doc, the correct way to handle with objects shared between pages is to use QWizardPage::registerField and QWizardPage::field.
I personally think is more simple, since we are under C++, to pass to the QWizardPage(s), in their constructors, a pointer to my shared object, since there's no risk on cuncurrent access on the shared resource. Every QWizardPage change the value of that object safely and it's shared between pages because the pointer location is the same.
What am I missing? Why the need of such methods?

Comment: Is it just me or do others not understand the question either?

Answer (score 0):

They are different approaches:

- With a shared pointer you need a member for each object you want to share, which means you need to change the interface of your classes.
- With the `field`-API you don't change the interface, *but* it is then not defined in the interface what fields exist. This means you should document them separately. This seems to me is the better way when having a multitude of fields.

  - Also note the automatic validation by the wizard:

    > If an asterisk (`*`) is appended to the name when the property is registered, the field is a mandatory field. When a page has mandatory fields, the *Next* and/or *Finish* buttons are enabled only when all mandatory fields are filled.
    >
    > To consider a field "filled", `QWizard` simply checks that the field's current value doesn't equal the original value (the value it had when `initializePage()` was called). For `QLineEdit` and `QAbstractSpinBox` subclasses, `QWizard` also checks that `hasAcceptableInput()` returns `true`, to honor any validator or mask.
    >   As you see: it's mainly a convenience feature. And it might save you from recompiling lots of stuff when working with bigger projects.

As you see: it's mainly a convenience feature. And it might save you from recompiling lots of stuff when working with bigger projects.